# How to pass Keyvault secrets to Invoke Azure Function task in YAML?

Tags: azure, yaml, azure-pipelines-yaml

Looking for a way to access keyvault secrets in the invoke Azure function activity in a YAML template,
The secret from the keyvault is the url for the azure function that I want to invoke in the yaml task.

The Issue is Task Invoke Azure function can only be done on a serverless agent but the keyvault secrets cannot be read in the serverless agent.

I have tried to set the variables as required dependency but that is not working. I have linked variable groups to the task the serverless agent is not able to access those secrets, I have also tried to re-assign values to global variables with keyvault secrets in a hosted agent and then invoke azure function, but that also does not work.

Is there a specific way to do this?

Comment: have you tried output dependencies ? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#use-outputs-in-a-different-job